# Training yolov8 with MPS on macbook

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov8

I am trying to train yolov8 on my custom dataset by this following code:

```py
model = YOLO('yolov8s.pt')

# train
results = model.train(
    data=data,
    epochs=epochs,
    batch=batch_size,
    imgsz=img_size,
    project=project_name,
    name=model_name,
    device=torch.device('mps')
)
```

But I got an error:

```
engine/trainer: task=detect, mode=train, model=yolov8s.pt, data=/Users/btp712/Code/Human Monitor/MOT17/mot17_data.yml, epochs=30, time=None, patience=50, batch=-1, imgsz=640, save=True, save_period=-1, cache=False, device=mps, workers=8, project=models/yolo, name=yolov8s_mot17_det10, exist_ok=False, pretrained=True, optimizer=auto, verbose=True, seed=0, deterministic=True, single_cls=False, rect=False, cos_lr=False, close_mosaic=10, resume=False, amp=True, fraction=1.0, profile=False, freeze=None, multi_scale=False, overlap_mask=True, mask_ratio=4, dropout=0.0, val=True, split=val, save_json=False, save_hybrid=False, conf=None, iou=0.7, max_det=300, half=False, dnn=False, plots=True, source=None, vid_stride=1, stream_buffer=False, visualize=False, augment=False, agnostic_nms=False, classes=None, retina_masks=False, embed=None, show=False, save_frames=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, show_labels=True, show_conf=True, show_boxes=True, line_width=None, format=torchscript, keras=False, optimize=False, int8=False, dynamic=False, simplify=False, opset=None, workspace=4, nms=False, lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=7.5, cls=0.5, dfl=1.5, pose=12.0, kobj=1.0, label_smoothing=0.0, nbs=64, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0, auto_augment=randaugment, erasing=0.4, crop_fraction=1.0, cfg=None, tracker=botsort.yaml, save_dir=models/yolo/yolov8s_mot17_det10
Overriding model.yaml nc=80 with nc=1

                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments                     
  0                  -1  1       928  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [3, 32, 3, 2]                 
  1                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [32, 64, 3, 2]                
  2                  -1  1     29056  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [64, 64, 1, True]             
  3                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [64, 128, 3, 2]               
  4                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [128, 128, 2, True]           
  5                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 256, 3, 2]              
  6                  -1  2    788480  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [256, 256, 2, True]           
  7                  -1  1   1180672  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [256, 512, 3, 2]              
  8                  -1  1   1838080  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [512, 512, 1, True]           
  9                  -1  1    656896  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.SPPF            [512, 512, 5]                 
 10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]                           
 12                  -1  1    591360  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [768, 256, 1]                 
 13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]                           
 15                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [384, 128, 1]                 
 16                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 128, 3, 2]              
 17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]                           
 18                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [384, 256, 1]                 
 19                  -1  1    590336  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [256, 256, 3, 2]              
 20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]                           
 21                  -1  1   1969152  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [768, 512, 1]                 
 22        [15, 18, 21]  1   2116435  ultralytics.nn.modules.head.Detect           [1, [128, 256, 512]]          
Model summary: 225 layers, 11135987 parameters, 11135971 gradients, 28.6 GFLOPs

Transferred 349/355 items from pretrained weights
TensorBoard: Start with 'tensorboard --logdir models/yolo/yolov8s_mot17_det10', view at http://localhost:6006/
Freezing layer 'model.22.dfl.conv.weight'
AutoBatch: Computing optimal batch size for imgsz=640
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/btp712/Code/Human Monitor/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    train_yolo(model_name='yolov8s_mot17_det',
  File "/Users/btp712/Code/Human Monitor/train_yolo.py", line 8, in train_yolo
    results = model.train(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/btp712/Code/Human Monitor/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/model.py", line 601, in train
    self.trainer.train()
  File "/Users/btp712/Code/Human Monitor/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/trainer.py", line 208, in train
    self._do_train(world_size)
  File "/Users/btp712/Code/Human Monitor/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/trainer.py", line 322, in _do_train
    self._setup_train(world_size)
  File "/Users/btp712/Code/Human Monitor/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/trainer.py", line 282, in _setup_train
    self.args.batch = self.batch_size = check_train_batch_size(self.model, self.args.imgsz, self.amp)
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/btp712/Code/Human Monitor/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ultralytics/utils/autobatch.py", line 27, in check_train_batch_size
    return autobatch(deepcopy(model).train(), imgsz)  # compute optimal batch size
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/btp712/Code/Human Monitor/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ultralytics/utils/autobatch.py", line 58, in autobatch
    properties = torch.cuda.get_device_properties(device)  # device properties
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/btp712/Code/Human Monitor/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 453, in get_device_properties
    _lazy_init()  # will define _get_device_properties
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/btp712/Code/Human Monitor/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 293, in _lazy_init
    raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
```

I have explored and known that this problem happening with macos, specially on models without support of cuda. Initially, I trained model without passing 'mps' to `device` and it ran too slow, about 1 hour per epoch becuase of training on cpu. Then I knew I could train on gpu by passing 'mps' to `device` but getting this error.

I am using macbook air m2. As I known, my laptop is not supported of CUDA.